# Chrome does not show updated contents of external JS file which is loaded dynamically in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have following simple HTML and JS code. When User selects Italian Language option then the JS code dynamically load an external JS file `language_it.js`.

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
function ChangePageLanguage()
{
var e = document.getElementById("langDD");
var lang = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

if (lang == "it")
{
    var scrptE = document.createElement("script");
    scrptE.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    scrptE.setAttribute("language", "JavaScript");
    scrptE.setAttribute("src", "language_it.js");
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    head.appendChild(scrptE);
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select onchange="ChangePageLanguage()" id="langDD">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="it">Italian</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

The `language_it.js` have following line of code:

```
alert ("Italian");
```

It works fine in Firefox but if I change contents of `language_it.js` then `Chrome` does not show the updated contents unless I restart the index.html page in `Chrome`. Is there any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your cache is stopping your script from updating properly, or you need it to be always uncached in production, you can always do something like this:

```
scrptE.setAttribute("src", "language_it.js?" + (Date.now() % 10000));
```

That will append a time-based string of digits that will almost always give you a unique number at the end of your URI, which should stop the browser from retrieving the file from cache.

Answer (score 7):

When developing on Chrome, you can disable the cache

- Press F12 to open the developer tools.
- On the lower right corner, click the gear icon.
- Check "Disable Cache".
- Reload the page.

Comment: Even after disabling the cache it worked for only one time. And when I test it using second value then same issue!!!

Comment: @NidaSulheri try clearing the cache first (ctrl+shift+del from the "beginning of time"), then disable caching in the developer tools, then load the page.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the .js file to refresh during development, disable the cache like Joseph suggested.

If you need the JavaScript file to refresh every single time it's called (if you're dynamically generating it for example), you can add a unique querystring to the filename which will cause the browser to retrieve it every single time:

```
scrptE.setAttribute("src", "language_it.js?ticks=" + new Date().getTime());​
```